# Is it true that for finite n, there exists $\varepsilon$ such that $\text{Pr}\left(\left\lvert X - \mu\right\rvert < \varepsilon\right) = 1$

Tags: probability, statistics

In the way that the WLLN states that, as $n \to \infty$, the probability a random variable takes on a value arbitrarily far from $\mu$ is equal to $0$, is there a similar result for a finite $n$. More specifically, is there a result that states something like:

For $n \geq 1$, there exists an $\varepsilon$ such that $\text{Pr}\left(\left\lvert X - \mu\right\rvert < \varepsilon\right) = 1$.

Intuitively this statement seems to be true, but I can't find a formal statement and derivation of it online.

Comment: I suppose you mean $X$ to be a sample mean with sample size $n$. There are random variables with unbounded support, which you cannot find a finite $\varepsilon$ to bound it.

Comment: Concretely, take $X_i$ to be iid $N(0,1)$. Then all sample means are $N(0,1/n)$, and have unbounded support.

Comment: @BGM, so assuming that the random variable $X$ has finite support, then such an $\varepsilon$ would exist, but otherwise not. Is that correct?